# Opening PDF in full-screen mode

Tags: pdf

I tried to make an HTML and open it in a fullscreen browser, but it doesn't show the PDF.

Is there a way to open a PDF in full-screen, page fit 100% to screen, without blending effects, just the PDF without any menu?

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to use a dedicated PDF app to do this than try to read PDFs in the browser. For example, you can [upload a PDF in Google Play Books via the web interface](https://play.google.com/books/uploads) and then read it in the Play Books app, which on KitKat supports fullscreen mode, even hiding the notification and navigation bars.

Other PDF apps might have similar features, though I know that QuickOffice doesn't.

Comment: thx, i tried an ebook reader app for now. not perfect but working. im not allowed to upload that pdf somewhere. its a mockup whick i would like to test on my device.